# Symfony functional tests in a sub-request oriented scenario

Tags: symfony, phpunit, twig

In a Symfony 2.6 / PhpUnit 4.6 environment, I am looking for a way to individually test one single request only, in a scenario where that request might invoke at a later stage (while rendering the template for example) a sub-request.

Concretely, given the following Page Controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class Page extends Controller{

    public function viewAction(){
        return ...
    }

}
```

Which will render a Twig template containing the following line, which will invoke a sub-request to the `Widget` controller:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Widget:footerLatest')) }}
```

The `Widget` controller has it's own logic, maybe it's pulling something from the database:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class Widget extends Controller{

    public function footerLatestAction(){
        $foo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ModelBundle:Foo')->findBy(...);

        return [
            'foo' => $foo
        ];
    }

}
```

In my functional tests for the `Page` controller I will mock the Doctrine dependencies

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

class PageControllerTest extends \Tests\TestCase{

    public function testDetailsView(){
        $someMock = $this->getMockBuilder('ModelBundle\Entity\SomeEntity')
                ->getMock();
        $entityManagerMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
                ->setMethods(array('persist', 'flush', 'getRepository', 'clear'))
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();
        $repositoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('ModelBundle\Repository\SomeEntityRepository')
                ->setMethods(['findOneBy', 'findBy'])
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();

        $client->getContainer()->set('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', $entityManagerMock);
        ...

    }

}
```

At this point the problem is clear: in each controller test I will make I have to take into account all the sub-requests it might invoke, and this thing snowballs to something which might look hell.

My thought is that I can safely consider that each request (either master or sub) should be treated as completely distinct things, and thus tested distinctly, ie the `Page` controller will have the `PageControllerTest` which will **not** invoke sub-requests (it would have nothing to do with any sub-request at all), even if it normally would. And the `Widget` controller would have it's own `WidgetControllerTest`.

So, how can I "disable/ignore" sub-requests in functional tests? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the controller then the whole logic behind the request must work. It is no longer a real unit test but a functional test. So all must work. Not just a small part of the request.

If you have a simple DB and are not using any driver specific things you can always switch to in memory SQLite DB.
Edit your config_test.yml like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                memory:   true
```

And prepopulate the DB with the data you need for the test.

If you can't use SQLite you can always configure a real DB with,for example, `test_` prefix. It will get a bit more comlicated if you want to put this into automated build/deplozment but definitely doable.